# Customize markup of email select field in Sprout Forms

Tags: templating, plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to customize the markup of an email select field in Sprout Forms, however, when I customize the markup with [Custom HTML](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/custom-html), as specified in the documentation, it outputs the actual `value` rather than purging it to hide them from spam bots. I just need to know what I should include in the options to purge these. Here is the code I've been using.

```
{% set recipient = form.getField('emailRecipient') %}  
<select name="fields[{{ recipient.handle }}]">
  {% for option in recipient.settings.options %}
  <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.value == value.value %}selected{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a bug. I've added it to our list to look into and will update this thread once it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been added in [Sprout Fields](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/fields) v2.1.0

You can now use the Email Select field via custom HTML and obfuscate email addresses. I've added [an example in the docs](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/fields/docs/overview/email-select-field):

```
{% set contact = craft.sproutForms.form('contact') %}

{% set emailSelectField = contact.getField('emailSelect') %}

<select name="fields[{{ emailSelectField.handle }}]">

  {% set value = contact is defined ? contact.emailSelect.value : null %}

  {% set options = craft.sproutFields.obfuscateEmailAddresses(emailSelectField.settings.options, value) %}

  {% for option in options %}

    {% if value != "" %}
      {% set selected = (option.selected == 1) ? true : false %}
    {% else %}
      {% set selected = (option.default == 1) ? true : false %}
    {% endif %}

    <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if selected %}selected{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}</option>

  {% endfor %}

</select>
```

Comment: I've somehow put myself in a situation where I have to pass the $option index in for the value attribute. I used loop.index0. It's better in our case because our option.values aren't unique, but option.value didn't work for us.